# Ionic 3 popover to cant add label or span tag

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I used Ionic 3 for my university  project, I getting some issue , i added  this code part `headding: 'SOMETEXT <ion-label class="special-txt">$100 </ion-label>`    to but its out put showing like this `SOMETEXT <ion-label class="special-txt">$100 </ion-label>` 
cant change on the color  for `.special-txt` and always shown from the out put  component

[image: Image example]

**.ts**

```
doAlertPayment() {
        let options = {enableBackdropDismiss: true};
        let alrt = this.popoverCtrl.create(AlertsystemPage, {
            type: '1',
            headding: 'SOMETEXT <ion-label class="special-txt">$100 </ion-label> 

            subHeadding: '',
            alertMessage: this.master.language.getLanguageLabel('paymentValidPeriod'),
            positiveBtnText: this.master.language.getLanguageLabel('confirmPayment'),
            negativeBtnText: '',
            responseData: '0',
            cssClass: 'custom-popover'
          },
          options);

        alrt.onDidDismiss(data => {
          if(data){
            this.showQRCode = true;
          }
          console.log("Action completed!");
        });

        alrt.present(); // present on center

    }}
```

**css**

```
.custom-popover .special-txt {color: #f44336;}
```

Comment: Can you create an example using 
https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @Darpan sir my code cant added on the stack-blitz getting error , i can upload images

Comment: @Darpan Sir updated my question

Comment: The data you are passing to the AlertsystemPage is custom data, so add your AlertsystemPage code to the question please, otherwise nobody knows how you are using them

Comment: For example you could use the passed `cssClass` classnames directly in your AlertsystemPage template:
`<div [class]="navParams.data.cssClass"></div>`